# Can components be hidden in Visualforce Page?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning

In Visualforce Page, I can use `$Lightning.createComponent` to create components. On the contrary, can I hide or delete components?

---

Visualforce Page

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    
    <script src="/support/api/52.0/interaction.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/support/api/52.0/lightning/opencti.js"></script>
    <div id="lightning"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function jumpCmp2() {
            $Lightning.use("c:TestApp", function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent("c:Test2Cmp", 
                {},
                "lightning",
                function(cmp) {
                    console.info('-Successful- CMP 2');
                });
            });
        }
        function jumpCmp1() {
            $Lightning.use("c:TestApp", function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent("c:Test1Cmp", 
                {},
                "lightning",
                function(cmp) {
                    console.info('-Successful- CMP 1');
                });
            });
        }
        $Lightning.use("c:TestApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:Test1Cmp", 
            {},
            "lightning",
            function(cmp) {
                console.info('-Successful-Init');
            });
        });

    </script>
    <div name = 'test' style="margin-top: 15px;">
        <button onclick="jumpCmp2();">Go to page 2</button>
        <button onclick="jumpCmp1();">Go to page 1</button>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <input type="hide" id="phoneHide"/>
        <input type="hide" id="callIdHide"/>
        <input type="hide" id="callTypeHide"/>
    </div>
    
</apex:page>
```

---

Lightning Component 1

```
<aura:component description="The container component that houses the UI of the adapter.">
    <div class="slds-box">
        <center>
            <div> --- Component 1 ---</div>
        </center>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

---

Lightning Component 2

```
<aura:component description="The container component that houses the UI of the adapter.">
    <div class="slds-box">
        <center>
            <div> --- Component 2 ---</div>
        </center>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

---

**Desired Result**

When I click `Go to page 2`
hide or delete component 1,
When I click `Go to page 1`
hide or delete component 2.

**GIF**
[image: GIF]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use different div containers to hold each component:

```
<div id="container1" style="display: none"></div>
<div id="container2" style="display: none"></div>
```

---

```
Object.entries({
  container1:'c:Test1Cmp',
  container2: 'c:Test2Cmp'
}).forEach(
    function([containerName, componentName]) {
        $Lightning.use("c:TestApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent(componentName, {}, containerName, function() {
                console.log(`Loaded component ${containerName}`);
            });
        });
    }
)
```

Then you can show/hide them at will:

```
function jumpCmp1() {
  document.getElementById('container1').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('container2').style.display = 'none';
}
function jumpCmp2() {
  document.getElementById('container1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('container2').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your continued enthusiastic help

Comment: I extended another question, how to pass parameters to the component in the VF Page   button method?

Comment: @ZhangOu The `{}` in the `$Lightning.createComponent` is where you pass in parameters. They must be public attributes (`<aura:attribute name="xyz" access="public" />`) in order to be set.

Comment: @sfdx  thank you for your reply The parameters filled in  `{}`  are passed when the component is initialized.
The new problem I encountered is, when I click the Go to 2 button, can the parameters in `jumpCmp2()` VF JS be passed to component 2?

Comment: I am looking forward to your reply. Any effective suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ZhangOu You should be able to use [pubsub](https://github.com/developerforce/pubsub), [LMS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel), [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), etc. Lots of different ways to communicate in LWCs, even across different containers.